# Orientation of a sphere

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around notions of an orientable two-sided surface in $3$ dimensional space.

For instance, the sphere in $\Bbb R^3$ is the set $\{ (x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 :  ||(x,y,z)|| = 1 \}$, and a normal vector that points outward of the sphere is given at any point $(x,y,z)$ by $xi + yj + zk$.

Now having said all that, which points are on the "inside" and which are on the "outside"? Perhaps I have misunderstood the concept. Any clarifications much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a different meaning, but when I hear "the points inside the sphere" I think of the set $\{ (x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 :  ||(x,y,z)|| < 1 \}$, and for outside $\{ (x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 :  ||(x,y,z)|| > 1 \}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of an [orientable surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientability) is not that some points are on the inside and some points are on the outside of the surface, but that there is a consistent, continuous, global normal vector field on the surface. This gives the idea of an "inside" and an "outside" to the surface.

Comment: Interesting. I read this in my multi-variable calculus textbook and the notion is not rigorously given. Why do you add the word "field" when you say "global normal"?

Comment: because it is a normal vector field.

Comment: So that given a point on the surface, you assign it a normal, and that is indeed a vector field. Ok, now this all makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

An orientable surface always has $2$ possible orientations. You could always take the opposite  orientation...

In other words on the sphere $S^2$ you could take the normal vector field given by $\bf {\vec n}(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)$;  or $\bf {\vec n}(x,y,z)=(-x,-y,-z)$ as the orientation.